# How to update msbuild on Azure?

Tags: azure, msbuild

In Azure SCM Debug Console, when I run `msbuild /version` I get:

```
msbuild /version
D:\home\site\wwwroot
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.23107.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

14.0.23107.0
```

When I run it on my work machine I get:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

14.0.25420.1
```

Version 14.0.25420.1 of msbuild is installed in "Microsoft Build Tools 2015 Update 3". Is there a way to update the msbuild version on my azure instance?

***Note:*** This is related to https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/14050

Comment: You can't upgrade msbuild yourself in App Service. Open an issue here and describe the problem - https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues. That's the repo for the SCM (Kudu) and App Service sandbox.

Comment: Filed https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2336. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the latest **Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform** and **Microsoft.Net.Compilers** NuGet packages on your WebApp as well as your Class Libraries and Console Apps will use the latest build tasks & props\targets, which resolves the issue I was seeing and avoids the need to update MSBuild in the Azure App Services environment.

For more details, see https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/2336